# Visual Studio 2012 (x64) - Windows Phone Toolkit - How to Add WP toolkit custom controls to toolbox in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk, windows-phone-toolkit

The problem is following:

I have *Visual studio 2012 (x64)* with *Windows Phone 8 SDK* installed on *Windows 8 (x64)*.

In my project (*WP8 App targeting WP 8.0 with .NET 4.5*), I have Added (*through NuGet*) Windows Phone Toolkit and **I would like to add the custom controls that it provides to toolbox**. Is there a way to do it?

*I managed it once but for some reason I was not able to add LongListSelector from toolbox after that.*

EDIT:

**WHAT I WANT IS FOR THE CUSTOM CONTROLS ADDED IN WP TOOLKIT TO BE SHOWN IN THE TOOLBOX in VS 2102**

Comment: Do you add reference in xaml header?

Comment: @MatDevWp8 : yep, i added

        xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

into the PhoneApplicationPage Definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/cd8fff44-3a5e-4441-8804-d5cb41507ce3/adding-toolkit-controls-to-the-toolbox?forum=wpdevelop).  When adding controls, browse to the WP Toolkit folder.  For your convenience, the specific answer is copied to here as following:

```
In my windows 8 machine it usually points to
your project where WPToolkit is installed
[WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16\lib\sl4-windowsphone71\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll]
Please note, Although, I have chosen a WP8 project, I had to choose the 7.1 dll to make to add it to the Toolbox. the wp8 folder failed to add.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download or browse Sample Codes of NuGet `WPToolkit` from http://phone.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest

Here, all the Custom Controls has been defined perfectly with samples. You can directly achieve the XAML and C# code through this.

Hope, this might be helpful to you. Don't forget to mark this an answer. If it helps you.

Comment: It's nice and gets me to where i essentially need to be, even though it does not answer my original question. ( it was how to get the custom controls in WP toolkit into toolbox in VS2012 ). I don't have enough points to give you the +1 vote, otherwise i would

Comment: It's okay. Mark it as an answer if you find something useful in that samples.

Comment: i couldnot get your question. thats y preferred a link

Comment: Didn't find the answer, but found a nice resource to have instead. I don't exactly need custom controls to be in the toolbox, but it's a nice thing to have. I'm gonna keep searching for my answer though.